# order a number of div's dependant on a certain php variable in each div

Tags: php, html, variables, foreach

I have a div called 'teams', which contians a number of div's with team members (as below).

Each team member needs to be ordered correctly using the $memberSequence.

```
<div class="teams">
   <div class="team-member">
      <?php echo $memberSequence; ?>
      <p class="name"><strong><?= $nameID ?></strong></p>
      <p class="title"><?= $positionID ?></p>
      <p class="tel">Dir: <?= $telephoneID ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="team-member">
      <?php echo $memberSequence; ?>
      <p class="name"><strong><?= $nameID ?></strong></p>
      <p class="title"><?= $positionID ?></p>
      <p class="tel">Dir: <?= $telephoneID ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="team-member">
      <?php echo $memberSequence; ?>
      <p class="name"><strong><?= $nameID ?></strong></p>
      <p class="title"><?= $positionID ?></p>
      <p class="tel">Dir: <?= $telephoneID ?></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

How would I order the above team members, dependant on the $memberSequence (if this variable contained for example 1 or 2 or 3).

I am pulling in $memberSequence using the following:

```
$memberSequence = fieldattach::getValue($this->item->id, 22, false);
```

Comment: if all of this comes from an array, then just sort the array.

Comment: You have to first show your full php code this is the output you want. show full code then something can be done.

Comment: I am pulling in $memberSequence using the following:

$memberSequence = fieldattach::getValue($this->item->id, 22, false);

Answer (score 1):

Usually some loop is used to output such a structure.

You should use sort ( http://php.net/sort ) before creating the HTML, for example:

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

If the data source is database, sorting should be done there (SELECT ... ORDER BY memberSequence).

Comment: Thank you... so say the array values are numbers. They could be 1, 2, 3 or they could be 3, 7, 9.